# How can I update alexa skill after publishing to skill store?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I wonder what happens behind the scenes when I publish my skill into the skill store.

Does it copy all my intent json to a different secure place ? Or does it still refers the intents in my alexa console ?

I wonder this because if I want to update my skill after I publish the skill, will the skill users be impacted ? 
Can I use a different skill endpoint after I publish my skill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your skill is published you will have a live version and development version. Both the live version and the development version of your skill will be shown in the developer console.

You can now **make changes only to the development version of the skill** like: change in the interaction model, endpoint change etc. Any change in the development version requires your skill to go through the **certification process again before its live** again.

When you submit your new version for certification, both versions remain in your list until the new version is certified. Once the new version is certified, it becomes live and replaces the previous live version. All the existing users will have the live/latest version of your skill. A new development version is then created so that you can continue making updates.

Comment: What about testing the skill on alexa device ? As the invocation name is same, which version will it choose, the dev one or live one ?

Comment: If its the same account under which the skill is developed/published then the dev one will be used. Even if the skill is published, the skill will be only available under "dev skills" in your Alexa app.

Comment: This helps. Thanks.